How to get filters on multiple columns at the same time
I am trying to filter multiple columns.
I only need to filter on the letter V.
When I push the button in Excel, the VBA code filters a column on a specific letter.
When I try this for multiple buttons it resets everything. I know that it is due to the code ws.AutoFilterMode = False. How do I change it so the filter on the other button remains active when I push the new button?
For example:
When I push the button, column D filters for "V".
When I push the second button, column I and D filter for "V".
Sub Time ()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Database voor slicer")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Set rng = ws.Range("P1:P2000")
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="V"
End Sub


Filter Data
Before

After FilterOne

After FilterTwo

Sub FilterOne()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Database voor slicer")
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="V"

End Sub

Sub FilterTwo()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Database voor slicer")
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="V" ' column 'D'
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="V" ' column 'I'

End Sub

Sub FilterNoVariables()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database voor slicer").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="V" ' column 'D'
        '.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="V" ' column 'I'
    End With
End Sub

